# heroku ! resource not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, foreman

I am trying to access/redeploy my very simple node.js heroku app running on cedar stack. I have moved the directory around on my harddisk, apart from that nothing has changed since last time doing it successfully.

The app locally / using foreman works ok, but whatever I do, except logging in, remotely fails with the kinda undescriptive "! resource not found" error message.

--
LOGIN - OK

09:13 ~/web/2012/heroku [master]$ heroku auth:login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: me@me.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Authentication successful.

FOREMAN - OK

09:14 ~/web/2012/heroku [master]$ foreman start
09:14:31 web.1  | started with pid 1695
09:14:31 web.1  | Listening on 5000
^CSIGINT received
09:14:33 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
09:14:33 web.1  | exited with code 1

ANYTHING ELSE - NOT OK

09:14 ~/web/2012/heroku [master]$ heroku ps
 !    Resource not found

### 09:14 ~/web/2012/heroku [master]$

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually see that if you don't have access to the application that you are trying to interrogate on Heroku or the application isn't in the account you are logged into.

Have a look at the output of `git remote -v` and make sure that the `heroku` end point is pointing at the git repo of the application you expect it to be.