# heroku pg:psql "no app specified"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to access my Heroku database with the usual command `heroku pg:psql` but I am getting :

```
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app <app name>
```

Although I am running it from the app folder. If I try `heroku pg:psql --app APPNAME` I get :

```
Resource not found
```

Has anything changed recently?

Comment: Run `git remote -v` and confirm that it shows 2 lines starting with `APPNAME`. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14558573/429758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I just needed to update my heroku toolbelt.